# How to reverse the sort order of the data shown on the X-axis of my chart?

Tags: 7, views, charts

My question is about [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) sorting. Newest entries (assume they are days within a month) are on the left, as shown in this chart:

[image]

But I want those newest entries to be on the right side, so I need to reverse the order.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. In that case, refer to [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929), especially the "Bonus tip" in it, which states:

> You may find it easier to start with a "Table" display and convert it to a chart display after setting up the data. It can be easier to visualize what the result of the chart will be if it's been laid out in a table first.

In this specific case: after you succeed in creating a view that is a table display (with the correct sorting), it should be straight forward to also do so for the Charts-display.

With only the limited details provided, it appears that you should **sort the data to be sorted using the field that you also used to create the X-axis of the chart** (whereas this sorting should be "ascending").